# Setting headlines with widths which differ from the width of the body text

Tags: header-footer, plain-tex

Using (plain) TeX, I'm trying to set the headline to a different width from that of the body of the text (i.e. hang page numbers to the outside of the text, as seen in the TeX Book).

Comment: Welcome! How are you trying to do this exactly?

Comment: if you're trying to "copy" the texbook, take a look at the file `manmac.tex` in the `.../tex/plain/base/` directory of a tex live distribution.  that contains the macros used for knuth's *computers & typesetting* series.  i haven't checked, but an educated guess says that `\llap` and `\rlap` are involved.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're guess is correct. Would you like to provide an answer?

Answer (score 2):

if you're trying to "copy" the *texbook*, take a look at the file
`manmac.tex` in the `.../tex/plain/base/` directory of a
tex live distribution. that file contains the macros used for
knuth's *computers & typesetting* series.

i haven't checked, but an educated guess says that `\llap` and
`\rlap` are involved.  this is confirmed by another experienced user.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\rlap` and `\llap`:

```
\input plipsum

\headline={%
  \ifodd\pageno
    \hfill{\it Chapter title}\rlap{\qquad{\bf\folio}}%
  \else
    \llap{{\bf\folio}\qquad}{\it Chapter title}\hfill
  \fi
}
\footline={}

\lipsum{1-20}

\bye
```

[image]

Instead of “Chapter title” you may want variable data, that's left as an exercise about marks.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to completely test the following, not even using the plain package.

```
\headline={\ifodd\pageno\rightheadline\else\leftheadline\fi}
    \def\rightheadline{\hbox{\hbox to \textwidth{\rlap{left}\hfil center\hfil \llap{right}}\rlap{\hbox to .25in{\hfil\the\pageno}}}}
\def\leftheadline{\hbox{\llap{\hbox to .25in{\the\pageno\hfil}}\hbox to \textwidth{\rlap{left}\hfil center\hfil \llap{right}}}}
```

I was able to test parts of it using LaTeX.

Comment: You don't need plain package; plain is a macro collection, just like LaTeX. You can just run `tex file.tex`, `pdftex file.tex`, `xetex file.tex` or `luatex file.tex` to use it (/them).